# Meaning of "taking a woman off to the hay bales"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "taking a woman off to the hay bales"?

For example, a group of friends is doing the famous Route 66 and, while crossing Arizona, one of the guys writes about the day on its Facebook:

"Seven vultures seen circling a carcass. Six Mustang horses seen trotting through the hill. **Two cowboys seen taking Mary off to the hay bales.** Etc."

*(added a bit more of context - I thought it was a common expression which would be understandable easily and feared that the context could bias or something)*

Comment: Never heard it before, but it suggests that they were preparing for a roll in the hay.

Comment: Doh... What's "a roll in the hay"?

Comment: What two people (generally of opposite genders) do in a haymow.  (Google it.)

Comment: I thought that the expression might be sexual but can't it also be used to mean something like "taking off to the sunset", like getting a ride somewhere?

Comment: After all, if it was a reference to having sex (with 2 guys, nonetheless), would the friends go around writing that? Then again, who knows - that depends.

Comment: It's possible that it's an idiom meaning to go off necking or some such, vs taking that next step.  Hard to say.  (There's also a vague chance that the implication was to go on a "hay ride", though that's usually done with several couples.)  (And, of course, it may be that it means literally that the cowboys were simply going to show her the haystack.)

Comment: @Dendi: Why do people write any of the stuff they write on Facebook? (This is a rhetorical question — I don't know the answer, either.)

Comment: @Scott - well, who knows. That's a very philosophical and open question, akin to "why do people act?". Or "why did the chicken cross the road?". Who knows...

Comment: No one knows, but the road has vowed to get even.

Answer (score 0):

"Two cowboys seen taking Mary off to the hay bales" is (probably) a play on the idiom ***a roll in the hay***, which is a euphemism for having sex.

The person who wrote it is trying to be funny. Of the many western cliches they've seen (vultures, horses, etc.), one of them was Mary being led away to have sex with two strapping cowboys. It's a play on the western imagery as well as a not so subtle jab at Mary (suggesting that she's promiscuous, or at least easy).

It's unlikely the writer saw any of these things (vultures, horses, cowboys). The writer is probably just using them for their value as archetypal images.

If you think this is a weird joke, just consider that some friends have no problem calling each other "slut" and "whore" in a joking manner. Your example is not as overt as that, of course, and the suggestion of promiscuity in it might be so weak as to not even register.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still find it an ambiguous situation... Everything else he wrote was humorist but directly true (the examples with the Vultures and Mustangs were just examples), so one would expect the trip to the hay bales to also be true. On the other hand, going to do that in sight of the mixed group of friends is pretty wild (though with the heat, craziness of the journey, whatever) and a friend exposing that in Facebook in a broader post doesn't sound very believable. Hence me thinking it was literal just with another meaning other than going to have sex, though maybe not...

Comment: Confusing comment. Sorry... Basically, from the whole context (which unfortunately only I have) I believe it to be directly true, just possibly not with that meaning (ex: a ride somewhere like a nearby town). I thought that expression would be a known expression. But it appears no one recognizes it or thinks it might mean anything else (in its direct meaning) other that going to have sex. Thanks for your answer.